# How to get day, month and year as integers from MonthCalendar in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MaxSelectionCount set to 1. I know how to get a date as a string, but I want to have day, month and year as three different variables.

Comment: Include some code and be more specific on your question...  I honestly have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the date as follows:

```
var startDate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
```

The returned property is of type [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0).
Therefore, you can use `startDate.Day`, `startDate.Month` or `startDate.Year` to access the [date properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Or use _SelectionStart_ as well